# How to know how many elements are on a page using codeceptjs

Tags: javascript, end-to-end, codeceptjs

In Codeceptjs, I don't find a way to count the number a certain element is present on the page. The `I.assertNumber` in the example is some kind of made up clause to hopefully express better what I am looking for.

```
Scenario('test something', (I) => {
    I.amOnPage('http://example.com`);
    I.assertNumber((locate('div.someclass'),20); 
    .. }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `seeNumberOfElements` or `seeNumberOfVisibleElements` methods

see in docs (maybe you use other helper(Puppeteer, Protractor, etc), so see in its doc)
https://codecept.io/helpers/WebDriver/#seenumberofelements
https://codecept.io/helpers/WebDriver/#seenumberofvisibleelements

Comment: Oops .. :) simple enough, I must have overlooked it somehow, thanks!

Comment: @Evgeny  Link broken